# Count number of non null matrix elements

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays something like `arr[26,20]` with the alphabet in the first position of each array.

So laid out in matrix form it would something like.

- ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
- //////////////////////////
- //////////////////////////
- //////////////////////////
- //////////////////////////

The forward slashes representing null values.

I'm trying to get the number of non null elements in a single colomn.

So the code I could use on a normal array would be

```
int number = arr[0].Count(s => s != null);
```

However, how would I do this for a matrix like described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Range()` to generate rows indexes:

```
int colIdx = 0; // column index to check
int num = Enumerable.Range(0,arr.GetLength(0)).Count(i => arr[i,colIdx] != null);
```

where `GetLength(dim)` gives the number of elements along dimension `dim` (0 - first dimension, 1 - second dimensions etc.).

Comment: Trying to use Enumerable, but perhaps I'm just not seeing what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my exact code.

`NumOfElem = Enumerable(0, MArray.GetLength(0)).Count(x => MArray[x, count] != null);`   

I'm receiving the error Enumerable is a type used like a variable.

Comment: Use `Enumerable.Range(...` not just `Enumerable(...`  ;-)

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. It's been a late night.

Comment: @shadowjfaith: Apologies, I just noticed I forgot Range also in my code. It's been an early morning for me instead :P

Comment: I gave up on this assignment, but thanks for the help.  This does work, but I made errors in my programming technique.

Answer (score 1):

you may simply use:

```
int columnIndex = 1;// column index to check
arr.Count(s => s[columnIndex] != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
arr.Cast<YourArrayElementType>().Count(s => s != null);
```

The reason is that a multi-dimensional array is a non-generic `IEnumerable`, but unfortunately not `IEnumerable<YourArrayElementType>`.

Oops, this counts non-null elements in the entire matrix, not just one column/row. So use digEmAll's answer instead. Or why not use a good old `for` loop?